# HowTo delete the Database ConnectionStrings stored in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2005 Team Edition for DB Professionals.

After starting "Data --> Schema Compare --> New Schema Comparison...", i can choose a database from a DropDown. Unfortunately there are some old references that i don't need anymore. How can i delete those entries?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I did recognize that the connections are stored in the Server Explorer. "View --> Server Explorer". The Data Connections stored there can be deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me - it *appeared* to work, but the deleted connection would re-appear when the solution was reloaded.  It turns out the resolution to my problem was really simple: there were references to connectionstrings in my web.config, and *this* is what was being used when populating the list in Server Explorer!

Answer (score 7):

You can manage them from the registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\SSDT\ConnectionMruList

Answer (score 3):

Yes can view your added schemas in the "Server Explorer" in Visual Studio. Just, right-click the schema and delete it.

Answer (score 2):

In the select schema connection window, click edit connection for the connection you don't want. The set it to a connection you already have and still want, this tricks it into removing itself.

It's the only way I've got them to remove!

Comment: Same here, they don't appear in the Server Explorer (VS 2015 and maybe 2013)

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2017:

- Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer.
- Select Properties.
- Click the Settings option in the left menu pane.
- Right click on the connection you want to remove.

KerPOW! Done! Gone!

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2015 MRU connections are stored here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ConnectionMruList

Comment: Make sure you close visual studio when you delete.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I have clicked on Project and Select the name of project on dropdown menu e.g. MyDemo Properties. On the side menu click settings then you will find connection string listed in a table then Delete those you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your web.config file and find the  tag.  You'll see all of your old and current connections in there you can delete the ones you no longer need.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me in VS 2015.  I could not find the registry entry mentioned.  Only the following steps worked for me:

1. Delete any forms that rely on datasets you will delete.
2. Delete datasets that rely on the connections.
3. Remove all connection strings from app.config.
4. Remove all "settings" from the project properties setting tabs.
5. Delete all data connections in server explorer (View->Server Explorer).
6. Rebuild the project.

Now when you add a new Data Source all the connections in the dropdown are gone.

As another user mentioned above, deleting the data connections in the server explorer is not enough.  When you exit VS and re-enter they come right back.